# Xamarin.Forms: Remove padding inside Button

Tags: button, xamarin, padding, xamarin.forms

I want to have a small button. The height of the button is 30. On some plattforms (Android, UWP) the text inside the button is cut off. That's because there is a padding between the text and the outside border.

One option is to make the button bigger, but there is enough space for the text. Is there an option for setting the inside padding?

Answer (score 14):

On Android, you can do this with styling.

**Resources/values-v21/styles.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/noPaddingButtonStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="noPaddingButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Set custom theme as application theme.

```xml
<application android:label="$safeprojectname$" android:theme="@style/myTheme"></application>
```

It's setting the left and right margin to `0dp`. The default style has a padding.

This is working on Android >= 5.  If you want to support lower android versions, you have to add multiple style folders and use other base themes like `Theme.Holo` or `Theme.AppCompat`.

---

Or you go for the Renderer:

```cs
using App6.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ZeroPaddingRenderer))]
namespace App6.Droid
{
    public class ZeroPaddingRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control?.SetPadding(0, Control.PaddingTop, 0, Control.PaddingBottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sven, I'm new to custom renderers. I want to add that custom renderer. I have it saved under my Droid project. How do I make sure my Button can get access to SetPadding method above in Xamarin.Forms? Thanks!

Comment: You have to crate a custom Xamarin.Forms Control `MyButton : Button` with a bindable property `Padding` and then use the shown renderer but with `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(ZeroPaddingRenderer))]` here is a step by step https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/

Comment: Or maybe easier use an Effect instead of custom renderer: http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=433

Comment: I'm going to try the custom renderer. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Before I screw up my code, can show you me an example of what a Bindable property for Padding would look like? The documentation link you sent does not show an example of creating a Bindable property. Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.bitbull.com/2015/01/17/creating-bindable-properties-in-xamarin-forms/ with type `Thickness` instead ob bool.

Comment: Great, almost got it. I have one more question... what the second parameter in Create<> What should it be?: public static readonly BindableProperty PaddingProperty = BindableProperty.Create<UIButtonWithoutPadding, Thickness>(s => s.Padding, whatisthis?);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109199/discussion-between-sven-michael-stube-and-kala-j).

Comment: does that only work for Material theme?

Answer (score 9):

One option is to use a Label instead of a Button, and use a TapGestureRecognizer instead of Click events. The Label gives you more control over the layout of the text than a Button, but you don't get the advantage of it being translated into the native button control on each platform.

Comment: I do that a lot. But I noticed a performance hit on Android compared to a button. 1) you have to exactly tap on the text (which is sometimes thin) and 2) the attached command doesn't fire as fast as with a button.

Comment: TapGestureRecognizers will conflict with ScrollViews also.

Comment: @François Is there a way to overcome tapping exactly on text?

Comment: you can cheat and add a transparent boxview on top of the label and add the tap gesture on the box. However, buttons offers more behaviors around a command that just recognizing a tap so I try to use them as much as possible.

Comment: @François WOW tx for your quick reply. Is there a way to achieve `Pressed` and `Released` events of a `Button` with `GestureRecognizer`s? I need information on the duration of the tap/click/mouse-down.

Comment: I've never tried. Why would you rewrite the button control? Is your issue the padding as in my initial post? Maybe you should ask an entirely new question?

Comment: @François my issue is getting rid of the `Padding` on Android indeed. Please see [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1702) and [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2220) suggestions. Any other ways to achieve `Press` and `Release` with zero padding other than custom renderers?

Comment: for some use cases this is not a suitable option. For example, if you need to use button within a listview viewcell together with the selecteditem or tapped event, it works but if you use label with the tap gesture together with the contextactions, it doesnt work. there is known bug for this in xamarin.forms github since 2016 and still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can play with the `FontSize` in order to fit the button `HeightRequest`, unless that you need to create a custom renderer to set the padding.

Comment: So there is no option. I could use different `FontSize` for each platform, but if I want to have it perfect I'll need the custom renderer.